# ColdFusion, if not outputting date... how to output a string instead?

Tags: coldfusion

I am getting data from a query and two of the outputs are dates:

```
<cfset qryResult = queryNew("status,start_date,end_date","varchar,date,date")>

<cfif qryFeedbackSurvey.recordcount> 

  <cfset querySetCell(qryResult, "status",qryFeedbackSurvey.response_count)>    
  <cfset querySetCell(qryResult, "start_date",qryFeedbackSurvey.start_date)>    
  <cfset querySetCell(qryResult, "end_date",qryFeedbackSurvey.end_date)>    

<cfelse>

  <cfset querySetCell(qryResult, "status","Get Feedback")>    
  <cfset querySetCell(qryResult, "start_date","">    
  <cfset querySetCell(qryResult, "end_date","")>    

</cfif>
```

When I dump this, if there is no date in the row, then it outputs `[empty string]`.

If there is no date available, how can I output something in place of the empty string. Is there a method to push a text string to that field?

Comment: Did you try dumping `qryFeedbackSurvey`?

Comment: @RRK and for the result, I can see dates where dates need to be, but where dates don't exist: `[empty string]`.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this?`<cfset querySetCell(qryResult, "start_date", len(qryFeedbackSurvey.start_date) ? qryFeedbackSurvey.start_date : 'No start Date')> `

Comment: OT: if this is supposed to be one row, I would return a struct. All this query manipulation seems a bit much.

Comment: @RRK has the right general idea and his comment is a suitable answer.  However, in order to make it work, the datatype for those columns would have to be `varchar`, not `date`, and you would have to format any dates you have.  Alternatively, you could also apply this logic in the sql in your database query.

Comment: Do you control the query? If it's your query, just set a default in the query itself.

Answer (score 1):

When you are calling querySetCell() for your dates, check to see what's in the date field. Set the qryResult field accordingly.

```
<cfif qryFeedBackSurvey.start_date eq "" or not isDate(qryFeedBackSurvey.start_date)>
     <cfset querySetCell(qryResult,"start_date","No start date specified")>
<cfelse>
     <cfset querySetCell(qryResult,"start_date",qryFeedBackSurvey.start_date)>
</cfif>
```